# Bootstrap rowspan, remove empty spaces between rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a container in to my form. The container height is about 4 bootstrap rows. Once I put the container into the second column of the first row, there is a white space that appears under the first column of the first row. Is it possible to remove that white space? 
This is how I have implemented my form. (divide into two col-6 columns is not a solution, it won't work when it comes to the mobile view). [jsfiddle exmple](https://jsfiddle.net/0n25341h/)

```html
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name<i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div style="width: 100% ; height: 250px; background-color: black;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="Name" #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="Name" #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the marked spaces, like the below image:
[image]

Comment: May I ask why it won't work when it comes to mobile view?

Comment: why should you used extra div in between row.. pls remove tat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style block for sizes md and above...

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .toggleDiv{ position:absolute; right:0; }
}
```

working snippet below:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .toggleDiv {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name<i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 toggleDiv">
    <div style="width: 100% ; height: 250px; background-color: black;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="Name" #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk required-span" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="Name" #Name class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate... you made my day... :)